# Composer throwing git error while installing module in drupal 8

Tags: git, composer-php, drupal-8

i am trying to install module via composer. it is throwing RunTime Exception in drupal 8

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

```
[RuntimeException]
Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout"https://git.drupal.org/project/coder.git" 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\d8-demo\vendor\drupal\coder" && \\
cd /D "C:\xampp\htdocs\d8-demo\vendor\drupal\coder" && \\
git remote add composer "https://git.drupal.org/project/coder.git" && git fetch composer
Cloning into 'C:\xampp\htdocs\d8-demo\vendor\drupal\coder'...
error:  waitpid for fetch-pack failed: No child processes
```

Answer (score 0):

Run composer update to make sure you have the latest version of composer installed.

If you are on windows make sure you are running GIT as administrator.